# WebRTC connection does not establish after successful signaling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc, p2p, simple-peer

I am using the simple-peer js library to create peer to peer connections in the browser. I have setup proper signaling through socket.io and most of the time everything works fine; hand-shake is successful and p2p connection is established.

But sometimes despite proper hand-shake, p2p connection does not initiate, no error is thrown. This happens consistently on a VPN but sometimes it can happen without VPN. I am using the default google STUN server for now and there is no TURN server provided.

Any enlightenment as to what could be the cause will be appreciated.

Comment: very difficult to exactly point out the error in this case, I would say keep a look at chrome://webrtc-internals/ it might help you debug.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that sometimes one of the peers "sits" behind the doubled NAT or symmetric NAT, VPN is a good example. You use only STUN server, STUN could not solve internal<->external IP of the client behind the doubled NAT. You need to set up TURN server for that. You can test with [free TURN](https://bloggeek.me/google-free-turn-server/), however, this is only to test the problem, not as a permanent solution. For permanent solution better to use your own TURN server.